# struggling to attach pdf to MIMEMultipart() email in Python

Tags: python, email, pdf, encoding

`pdf = MIMEText(open('out.pdf', 'rb').read())`
gives me "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'"

`pdf = MIMEText(open('out.pdf', 'r', errors='ignore').read())`
works but the pdf looks terrible on the client side. But I've been unable to configure encoding that works. Any suggestions here?

Thanks!

Comment: I should add that I have tried using MIMEApplication() rather than MIMEText() and that gives no errors, but nothing appears in the email on client side.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of the code you use to send the email? Also, what means "looks terrible"?